# Filling label value with javascript. Label empty in code behind after postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some text that needs to be changed after a click of a button. The button triggers a Javascript. This Javascript changes the value of the label. When I check the value of the label in the in different places its always empty.
I check the value of the label in page load and the pre render.

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

         string siteALias = lblSiteAliasDiscription.Text; //empty
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         string siteALias = lblSiteAliasDiscription.Text; //empty
}

function setDiscription(siteAlias, discription) {
            alert(siteAlias);
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_lblSiteAliasDiscription").InnerHTML = siteAlias;
            alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_lblSiteAliasDiscription").InnerHTML);

        }
```

Both alerts are filled in the right way, this is why I'm sure the label gets clear after the Javascript runs. Is there a way to read be able to read the label with the filled in value in the code behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html controls like labels, spans, divs don't post their values to the server.
But Input controls maintains changes in viewstate.

So, you can use disabled textbox instead of label or use one more hidden field and assign same value to that hidden field of label and access that from code behind.

Thanks.

Comment: Any Idea how I can show the textbox as a label? (without the grey box)

Comment: use this style sheet: `color:Black;border: 0px;background-color: #FFFFFF;`

Answer (score 1):

the label is not the client form's element,you can use the hiddenfield(its client element is input type="hidden") or textbox(its client element is input type="text") to do it,code like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myHF" runat="server" />

<script>
    document.getElementById("<%=this.myHF.ClientID %>").value = siteAlias;
</script>
```

the code behind:

```
string siteALias = this.myHF.Value;
```

Comment: This is a good way but the client needs to see the label too... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: you are welcome!you can use the hiddenfield to post the data to server and use the label to display.